# Resolve on parent state doesn't run on each child state change

Tags: angularjs

I am building an `AngularJS` app (using `router-ui`) that uses a tab style navigation. The users page, for example, will have the following tabs:

- Listing (will always be the main tab and list all users. Upon selecting a user on this tab, the rest will be come `active`
- Account Details
- Contact Details
- Notes
- etc

Now, I am using a service called `entityIdPersistenceService` to remember the ID of the user selected on the listing tab. In my routes, I am doing something like the below to notify the child tabs of the selected userId (so they can grab the necessary data), however it seems like alot of repetitive code. Is there a better way to provide my selected id to all other tabs?

```
    resolve: {
        entityId: function(entityIdPersistenceService) {
            return entityIdPersistenceService.getId();
        }
    }
```

It seems like alot of repetitive code. I added it to the parent state, however it looks like the code only runs once on the parent state, and not on every child state change.

Are there any better ways of doing something? Ideally id like to put this on the parent state and have it run at each route change.n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All pages related to a user should have UserId somewhere in the url and in route parameters:

```
.state('user.accountDetails', {
  url: "/users/{userId}/account",
  templateUrl: "..."
})
.state('user.contactDetails', {
  url: "/users/{userId}/contact",
  templateUrl: "..."
})
```

In this way the UserId will be stored in url instead of the service and every child controller will be able to get it via $stateParams.userId

Comment: Thanks admax. How would I go about for when a new user is being created? How can I tell my other routes (I am using `sticky` routes from `ui-router-extras`) that they are in "create" mode? Perhaps the userid could be a 0 or something like that?

Comment: you can do special set of routes for new user like 'users/new/account' etc